# Connect each of the subscription and retrieve the resourcegroupname

Tags: azure

please help me to write a script to connect to each of the subscription from "Get-AzureRmSubscription | ft Name" and run the Get-AzureRmOperationalInsightsWorkspace to retrieve the workspaces assigned to it.

thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Unfortunately, as written, this is a "write code for me" type of question. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: sorry about that, I was blocked during assing the subscriber name to   Set-AzureRmContext. But later i ahve figured out the solution. here is the script which i came up with for this

Comment: Please, as I stated initially, *edit your question.* Don't post extra details in comments, *especially* code (or script) which needs to be formatted. What you posted (as a comment) is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

```
$subs = Get-AzureRmSubscription | Select-Object SubscriptionName, SubscriptionId 
    foreach($sub in $subs)
    {
        $subName =$sub.SubscriptionName
        Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName $subName | Out-Null
        Write-host "Subscription Name: " $subName
        Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Format-Table ResourceGroupName
}
```